# cannot change content of div - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I would like to change the contents of a div, using javascript and `innerHTML`.

I cannot get it to work. I just added the code for changing the div, before that the code was working fine. I double checked the syntax.

I'm using webshims, openlayers and jquery/javascript

In the in the console I see

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
imagegaledit - myFile.php :768
so.onmessage - myFile.php :324`

768 is that line
`document.getElementById("imgedtitle").innerHTML=mnmi[0];`

and 324 is this 
`imagegaledit(0);`

Little help?
Thanks

**edit**
websockets work and responce fine

Here is the code (concise and simplified)

```
    <!doctype html>

    <header>    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html">

    <script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js-webshim/minified/extras/modernizr-custom.js"></script>  
    <script src="js-webshim/minified/polyfiller.js"></script>
    <script>    
        $.webshims.polyfill();  
    </script>

    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <!--open layers api library-->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='OpenLayers.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>

    //openlayers vars and stuff here...

    function init(){

       //when a point on map clicked...
       function selected_feature(event){
             //some openlayers magic...
              var so = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000");         

              so.onerror=function (evt) 
               {response.textContent = evt;}

                so.onopen = function(){
                response.textContent = "opened";
                so.send(JSON.stringify({command:'map',fmid:jas}));
                 }


                so.onmessage = function (evt) {    
                  var received_msg = evt.data;
                  var packet = JSON.parse(received_msg); 
                  //pass data to var and arrays...                       
                 imagegaledit(0);
                }
          }//closes function selected_feature

    }//closes init

    function imagegaledit (w){
        if (w==0){
           document.getElementById("imgedtitle").innerHTML=mnmi[0];
          }
    }//closes imagegaledit 


</script>    

    <body onload='init();'>
        Title</br><div id="imgedtitle"> </div> </br>
    </body>
```

Comment: fiddle or other demo?

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight This is a huge file with a lot of `include_once('header.php');` for example, and also other files. Also contains php. So, no unfortunately...

Comment: Just a thought, can u verify that DIV "imgedtitle" exists after page is loaded? Perhaps something overwrites page content

Comment: @YuriyGalanter How can I check that?

Comment: Just examine page content in Developer Tools (e.g. in Chrome F12 and Elements Tab)

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Thanks. For some reason `imgedtitle` disappears after the websockets is done responding. How can I fix/debug this?

Comment: I am not that familiar with websockets, but try to locate any part that can override html markup. How the modified page is different from the original markup? What's get inserted there?

Answer (score 0):

You need a closing script tag:

```
</script> 
<body>
```

Comment: There is a closing tag in my script. I jusy forgot to paste it in my post. I edited the question. Thanks for pointing out